# Is it possible to use `__date` for a `timestamp` field in `filterset_fields` list of `DjangoFilterBackend`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `ListAPIView` to list the records from my database table which is represented as `ExpiredOrders(models.Model)` in `models.py`.

The Django model has several columns along with `created_at` and `modified_at` as ***timestamp***.

I want to filter the records on the `created_at` against the query parameters `created_at`.

I am trying to use the `DjangoFilterBackend` to achieve the same.

```
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_fields = ['craeted_at__date']
```

However, it return me an error -

```
'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: created_at__date
```

As `created_date` is a ***timestamp*** and in query parameter I will only get the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`, I am using `__date` to make the record of database table comparable with the query parameter.

The other way to achieve this is -

```
def get_queryset(self):

        try:

            queryset = ExpiredOrders.objects.filter(created_at__date=self.query_params['created_at'])

        except:

            queryset = ExpiredOrders.objects.all()
        
        return queryset
```

I want to know if it is possible to get it done by just defining the **filed name** in the list `filterset_fields`.

Also, please explain me what does this `__` means here.

Best to my knowledge it is a convention to represent class variable or methods which must not be used with the objects of other class or subclasses. Perhaps, this concept is known as `name mangling` in Python.

In the Django documentation I have seen many of these `--`.
Some of those are -

`gte` - **greater than or equal to**

`lte` - **less than or equal to**

`et` - **equal to**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FilterSet` class to create a filter with custom filters.

```
class ExpiredOrderFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    created_at__date = filters.DateFilter(field_name='created_at__date')

    class Meta:
        model = ExpiredOrder
        fields = ['created_at',]
```

Now instead of `filterset_fields` user `filterset_class`

```
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_class = ExpiredOrderFilter
```

Comment: I have more then one field in `filterset_fields` how will I be able to make it work with `filterset_class`

Comment: define as many fields as you want in the class. There is no limit to the number of fields you can define in the filterset class.